# kendo dropdown list value not getting correctly passed to the server side code

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui

I have implemented kendo dropdownlist controls in my angular 7 application. I am binding the dropdownlist to an object which correctly binds the data and renders on the screen.

When i change the dropdown to another value and try to save it, I can see that the property in the model contains id of the changed value but not the object by itself.  Also another thing concerning is that on the server side .net code, it doesn't have the latest changed value.

I think the reason could be that in property get method the filtering is happening by this.Entity.PRIMARY_CLASS_ID. Here Entity refers to public FUND Entity { get; set; } in the viewmodel. On the clientside the dropdownlist is bound to FundDetails.PrimaryClasses and hence value of the ntity.PRIMARY_CLASS_ID gets untouched. So do I need to implement valuechange property to amend this value.

Could anybody tell me if am missing something.

UI

```
 <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2 col-form-label header">Primary Class</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails.PrimaryClasses.DESCRIPTION}}</div>
                    <kendo-dropdownlist  *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:350px" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.PrimaryClasses" [data]="FundDetails.Classes" [filterable]="false" textField="DESCRIPTION" [valuePrimitive]="true"
                    valueField="ID"></kendo-dropdownlist>
                </div>
```

Component

```
saveManager() {
        this.fundService.createFund(this.FundDetails)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.getFundDetails(this.SelectedFundId);
                this.EditMode = !this.EditMode;
            },
                err => {
                    this.Error = 'An error has occurred. Please contact BSG';
                },
                () => {
                });
    }
```

ViewModel

```
public class NewFundViewModel
    {

        public NewFundViewModel()
        {
            Products = new List<Product>();
        }

        public FUND Entity { get; set; }
        public List<FUND> Entities { get; set; }

        public List<VEHICLE_TYPE> VehicleTypes { get; set; }
        public List<DOMICILE> Domiciles { get; set; }
        public List<CLOSURE_STATUS> ClosureStatuses { get; set; }
        public List<INVESTMENT_STATUS> InvestmentStatuses { get; set; }
        public List<ACCOUNT_MANDATE> AccountMandates { get; set; }
        public ICollection<FUND> FlagshipFunds { get; set; }
        public FUND_CLASS PrimaryClass;
        public List<FUND_CLASS> Classes { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public List<int> BloombergRequiredIds { get; set; }
        private FUND_CLASS _primaryClass;
        private VEHICLE_TYPE _vehicleType;
        private DOMICILE _domicile;
        private CLOSURE_STATUS _closureStatus;
        private INVESTMENT_STATUS _investmentStatus;
        private FUND _flagshipFund;
        private ACCOUNT_MANDATE _accountMandate;

        public string SelectedHfrProduct
        {
            get
            {
                return Entity.HFR_ID.HasValue() && Products.Any(x => x.ShortName == Entity.HFR_ID)
                    ? Products.First(x => x.ShortName == Entity.HFR_ID).Name
                    : null;
            }
        }

        public FUND FlagShipFund
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.Entity.FLAGSHIP_FUND_ID == null) return null;
                 _flagshipFund = this.FlagshipFunds?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == this.Entity.FLAGSHIP_FUND_ID);
                    return _flagshipFund;

            }
            set
            {
                _flagshipFund = value;
            }
        }

        public INVESTMENT_STATUS InvestmentStatus
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.Entity.INVESTMENT_STATUS_ID == null) return null;
                _investmentStatus = this.InvestmentStatuses?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == this.Entity.INVESTMENT_STATUS_ID);
                return _investmentStatus;
            }
            set
            {
                _investmentStatus = value;
            }
        }

        public CLOSURE_STATUS ClosureStatus
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.Entity.CLOSURE_STATUS_ID == null) return null;
                 _closureStatus = this.ClosureStatuses?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == this.Entity.CLOSURE_STATUS_ID);
                return _closureStatus;
            }
            set
            {
                _closureStatus = value;
            }
        }

        public DOMICILE Domicile
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.Entity.DOMICILE_ID == null) return null;
                _domicile = this.Domiciles?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == this.Entity.DOMICILE_ID);
                return _domicile;
            }
            set
            {
               _domicile = value;
            }
        }



        public FUND_CLASS PrimaryClasses
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.Entity.PRIMARY_CLASS_ID == null) return null;
                _primaryClass = this.Classes?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == this.Entity.PRIMARY_CLASS_ID);
                return _primaryClass;
            }
            set
            {
                _primaryClass = value;
            }
        }

        public VEHICLE_TYPE VehicleType
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.Entity.VEHICLE_TYPE_ID == null) return null;
                _vehicleType = this.VehicleTypes?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == this.Entity.VEHICLE_TYPE_ID);
                return _vehicleType;
            }
            set
            {
                _vehicleType = value;
            }
        }

        public ACCOUNT_MANDATE AccountMandate
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.Entity.ACCOUNT_MANDATE_ID == null) return null;
                 _accountMandate = this.AccountMandates?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == this.Entity.ACCOUNT_MANDATE_ID);
                return _accountMandate;
            }
            set
            {
                _accountMandate = value;
            }
        }

        public string HFRFundName { get; set; }


    }
```

save method

```
 [HttpPut]
        [SkipTokenAuthorization]
        public void CreateFund(NewFundViewModel model)
        {

            var fundService = GetService<FUND>();

            var fund = fundService.GetWithIncludes(model.Entity.ID);

            if (fund != null)
            {
                fund.NAME = model.Entity.NAME;
                fund.IS_ANONYMOUS = model.Entity.IS_ANONYMOUS;
                fund.PRIMARY_CLASS_ID = model.PrimaryClasses.ID;
                fund.VEHICLE_TYPE_ID = model.VehicleType.ID;
                fund.FLAGSHIP_FUND_ID = model.FlagShipFund?.ID;
                fund.INVESTMENT_STATUS_ID = model.InvestmentStatus.ID;
                fund.CLOSURE_STATUS_ID = model.ClosureStatus.ID;
                fund.DOMICILE_ID = model.Domicile.ID;
                fund.ACCOUNT_MANDATE_ID = model.AccountMandate?.ID;
                fundService.Update(fund);
            }
            else
            {


            }

        }
```

Comment: rather than using the ngmodel for the object, save the id in  a variable like [(ngModel)]="selectedPrimaryClassId" or something. Then once the user submits, do whatever you are setting based on the set id (find the object from FundDetails.Classes with the selected id and set it to primaryClass object)..  kendo is really confusing with model binding.. There is also k-model as well when you are binding objects directly. You can also look for k-model too. good luck

Comment: if i take first option [(ngModel)]="selectedPrimaryClassId" how do I set selectedPrimaryClassId in the component code and how is the dropdown going to understand

Comment: from my understanding user selects the dropdown value and submits the page. So you basically set the PrimaryClass from the FundDetails.Classes.
Create a variable in your component like selectedPrimaryClassId. 
Then use it like [(ngModel)]="selectedPrimaryClassId" in your dropdown.
Then once user submits the form, loop through the FundDetails.Classes list and find the matching class with that selectedPrimaryClassId which will give you the selected class objectThen you can set that class that you found by using the id, to FundDetails.PrimaryClasses object

Comment: Sorry I am still not clear. When the page first loads how is selectedPrimaryClassId initialised

Comment: I think I found the answer. setting ngmodel to  [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.Entity.PRIMARY_CLASS_ID" did the trick. There was no need to add a field in the component code but just binding the model to the id in the entity did the trick. Thanks @curiousboy as your suggestion set me thinking

Comment: I shall test and see if it works and shall update the post

Comment: aah.. Im glad you found it. I was looking an example for you for the k-ng-model (which was used in AngularJS but not sure how it is Angular) anyways.. glad it is working.